# Edge-transitive Cayley graphs

Tags: graph-theory, cyclic-groups, algebraic-graph-theory, cayley-graphs

Find all edge-transitive Cayley graphs on cyclic group of valency 3.(Up to isomorphism)

**My solution :** So since the valency has to be equal to 3 $\Rightarrow$ the $|S|=3$. Take a cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Then Cay($\mathbb{Z}_n$,S), S defined as before is edge- transitive on a cyclic group. And it is edge-transitive

**My quation:** Are graphs of such kind the only ones that are edge-transitive Cayley graphs on cyclic group of valency 3? And if yes, then how can i show it?

Comment: It does not follow that, because $|S|=3$, the Cayley graph with connection set $S$ is edge-transitive. Consider, for example, $S=\{-1,1,3\}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$, where some edges lie in triangles and others do not.

Comment: Ah true! Then maybe there should not be elements that are inverses of each other in a set S?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are considering Cayley graphs, the connection set $S$ must be inverse-closed. Since it has size $3$, it must contain the unique involution $y$ of the cyclic group $G$. Let $x^{\pm 1}$ be the other two elements of $S$. We may as well assume that $G=\langle x,y\rangle$. There are two cases, depending on whether $y\in\langle x \rangle$ or not. If it is, then then graph is a Mobius ladder, if not then $x$ has odd order (otherwise $G$ would not be cyclic) and the graph is a ladder (or prism) of order twice odd. None of the graphs in the second category are edge-transitive, whereas in the first one, the first two graphs are edge-transitive (they are isomorphic to $K_4$ and $K_{3,3}$.)